# php simple html dom parser how to get the content of html tag

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am trying to get the specific tag content, but seems I am not able to do so using following function

```
<?PHP
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function read_page($url = 'http://google.com')
{
        $doc = new DOMDocument();

        $data = file_get_html($url);

        $content = $data->find('div#footer');

        print_r( $content);

}

read_page();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$data->find('div[id="footer"]')`

Comment: i tired that as well as $data->find('div[id=footer]') still can see empty array

Comment: yeah, it returns too much stuff, all the children and grand children and so on... i need something simple to get the content not all classes, styles etc.

Comment: It's supposed to do that. Have you read the documentation? If you just need the content, no html, use: `$footer = $data->find('#footer', 0); echo $footer->plaintext;`

Comment: thanks for your responses, i won't use php for parsing anymore.